# StateT and IO Monad combination

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I want to use the StateT Monad to read a string from a socket handle and append it into the state and repeat. Any idea how can I make this work?

What I have so far is something like this:

```
sessHandleCmd :: Handle -> StateT String IO ()
sessHandleCmd hdl = get >>= \s -> put s >> sessHandleCmd hdl

runSession :: Handle -> IO ()
runSession hdl = 
  execStateT (sessHandleCmd hdl) "" >> return ()
```

Not quite sure how to do a `hGetLine hdl` inside `sessHandleCmd`.

Comment: Using [`liftIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO) (or just [`lift`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift))

Comment: Nice, it worked, thanks. `sessHandleCmd hdl = lift (hGetLine hdl) >>= \x -> lift (print ("yeap, it works! " ++ x)) >> sessHandleCmd hdl`

Comment: Note that `lift` distributes over bind, so you could also write your demo `lift (hGetLine hd1 >>= print ("yeap, it works! " ++ x)) >> sessHandleCmd hd1`

Comment: Do you want to add your answer so I can mark it as correct?